# Core Date One-To-One Sorting

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a core data model that has two entities, Bid and Result.

I want them sorted initially in a section where the bid has no result i.e. the relationship from Bid to Result is nil, then I want this sub sorted by date.

Ideally I would have two sections:

1. Bids with no Result sorted by date
2. Bids with a result sorted by date

Due to the relationship being potentially nil I see very erratic results. Using two NSSortDescriptors first sorting on the relationship and then on the date will work for a few entries then seems to randomly blow up.

E.g.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sectionSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"result" ascending:YES];
 NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
```

How should I sort entities by a relationship that could potentially be nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nil should evaluate to zero and non-nil to non-zero so you can sort on nils. I think the problem maybe elsewhere.

I would suggest trying to sort just with the nils and see if that works. That at least will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere, when sorting on a one-to-one relationship you are sorting on a foreign key

Comment: Actually, you're not because Core Data doesn't have foreign keys. It's not SQL. If you meant you were trying to sort on an attribute of objects belonging to another entity other than the one being fetched, then yes.

Comment: when using a sql store your sort runs in the store. The relationship is modelled using foreign keys.

Comment: That's somewhat akin to getting involved in the details of writing a file to disk when using an xml store. How Core Data freeze dries the object graph isn't a relevant detail. People get in a lot of trouble trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms.